# Date Picker automatically popping up when page is open only in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

When I open up my page in IE10 for some reason the date picker is automatically opening and appearing on the screen. In firefox it is working properly and does not pop up until you click the text box it is associated with.. Does anyone know why this would be happening in IE10?

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


Date:<input type="text" name="purchasedate" id="datepicker" required="yes" message="Please enter date acquired." mask="99/99/9999">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it is because your input takes the focus automatically when the page is loaded. Try

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepicker" ).blur();
```

to remove the focus.